# UgilfyJS (version 2) -- how to get it to not drop unused

Tags: uglifyjs

Uglify drops variables it (wrongly) considers unused. It also warns about functions that it (wrongly) thinks are not referenced, but I have not looked yet to see if it actually drops them. It just doesn't see the whole universe at once -- none of these things it has identified as unused or unreferenced are unused or unreferenced. What CLI option will make it keep everything. My current CLI option list is:
    --compress sequences,drop_debugger,conditionals,comparisons,evaluate,booleans,loops,hoist_funs,if_return,join_vars,cascade,warnings 
    --lint 
    --mangle 
    --screw-ie8 
    --source-map $<.map 
    --verbose 
    -- peramble ... copyright ...

Answer (score 0):

Unused is an option of compress.

unused (default: true) -- drop unreferenced functions and variables (simple direct variable assignments do not count as references unless set to "keep_assign")

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2